# Most elegant way to resize an image to fill but not exceed browser window?

Tags: html, css

I have a layout with multiple images, both portrait and landscape. I would like to make each image take up as much space as possible within the browser window, whilst remaining entirely visible.

Is there a simple way to do this? I've tried searching but everything coming up is for making a single full screen DIV or image, rather than the multiple images I'd like to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `background-size` property, which has a value `cover`, that does exactly this. For older IE browsers which don't support this, a jQuery CSS hooks fix has been made available.

You just have to layout your DIVs using proportional CSS width values, and then assign each one a covering background image.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you are looking for something like this: http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/images.html